# Multiple consecutive individual ADB backup/restore without prompt

Tags: adb, backup

I was looking into how to do batch backups through individual adb backup/restore commands (to have separate .ab files per package/application/data/etc.) (I'm aware of the Helium (Carbon) desktop app as an option for this - would be interested in writing my own script for fun anyway).

The reason for wanting to create individual .ab files vs a large one is I want to be able to have partial backup/restore functionality for just individual packages, and not have to do, for example, 50 apps all at once.

The main obstacle at the moment is that every time a backup/restore occurs, user input has to be given when the prompt comes up - is there a way around this to be able to use adb backup/restore for multiple individual packages through something like a shell script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `adb shell input tap <x> <y>` where x and y are the coordinates of where you would like to tap on the screen (can show coords in Developer Options).  I was able to use this code to restore an individual backup:

```
#$1 is backup file

adb restore ${1} &
sleep 2
adb shell input touchscreen tap <x> <y>
wait
```

I found it useful to sleep for a couple seconds after the restore command, but it may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So, it would appear that there's no built in and (at least seemingly) intended way for us to do this.

Instead, this is possible through the `adb shell sendevent` command - this can emulate touch input from a computer with the adb tools (and any relevant drivers) installed, provided the phone has provided adb access to that specific machine.

Events can be recorded using `adb shell getevent` and replayed with `adb shell sendevent`. A user could then record the accepting button presses, and save a script that replays them. Of course, this introduces issues such as when there's a screen overlay (e.g. from red shift lighting apps) preventing pressing of the button, if something else appears (maybe a chat bubble, etc.), and any other number of obstructions, so it's a workaround at best.

Answer (score 0):

this seems particularly odd, but in that expected google evil way.  From my own incomplete but growing understanding of things- you can convert the restore file to a tar file by changing the first 24 bytes.  So then the question is, would a simple tar extraction in a particular way (remounting something or other rw temporarily?) accomplish the same thing the adb restore is doing?  Of course the source is theoretically all there.  I was planning on trying things out eventually and seeing if they seem to work good enough to justify not caring enough to dig through that source.  Yes, this is a pretty crappy answer, but it seems worthwhile as a placeholder until a little adb shell script with tar invokage or the like takes its place, which is what I presume the original questioner and I would like to see.